# IntelliJ IDEA - GUI Designer - Cannot preview form

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea

When I create a GUI form in IntelliJ IDEA, clicking on the  [Preview menu item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6GOU.png)
creates the Error:

*Cannot preview form '.../Main.form' Reason: Class not found: javax.swing.JPanel*

However, manually creating a main method in the linked class and running the latter, will create my application window without problems:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("UBPrivacy");
    frame.setContentPane(new Main().panel1);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

In my project structure, I have chosen Project SDK: java 9.0.1 
In my platform settings, SDK 9.0 has all the necessary paths configured (java.desktop, etc.).

I wonder if this is an IntelliJ IDEA bug or if I somehow misconfigured my classpath, modules or something else. (Since my manual main RUN works successfully.)

Thanks in advance for any help on this topic.

Comment: Looks like a bug specific to Java 9. If it works with Java 8, please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA and attach a sample project to reproduce.

Comment: Works with Java 8. Thanks for your quick response. Will submit the bug report in the next days!

Comment: The bug was reported by another user: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-191412.

Comment: Thank you 100x for this.  I was smashing my head on the keyboard wondering why I couldn't get it to work with 9.0.4.   It wouldn't red squiggle JPanel, and I could even jump to the source, but it kept saying it couldn't find it.  It was driving me bonkers.

Answer (score 10):

2 Years late and the bug still persists...

For anyone that re-discovered this question. You need to downgrade your project SDK from Java 9,10,11 to Java 8

Answer (score 0):

I found the right way is set

"javac2.instrumentation.includeJavaRuntime=true " in build.properties file

you can try it